# Firebase database not getting all key/values from android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I am using firebase database for real time chat but it only sometimes it skips key/value inside to add into database

[image]

That's how i am adding data into Firebase database

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("Message_From",  userSession.getUserFname() + " " +  userSession.getUserLname());
                            map.put("Message_To", UserName_Intent);
                            map.put("Message", download_URI.toString());
                            map.put("Time", time);
                            map.put("Type","Video");
                            map.put("token_From",Sender_FCMToken);
                            map.put("token_To",FirebaseToken_Intent);
                            map.put("UUID", Random_UUID);

                            String Temp_Key =  databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            Map<String, Object> RoomKey = new HashMap<>();
                            databaseReference.updateChildren(RoomKey);
                            DatabaseReference message_Root =  databaseReference.child(Temp_Key);
                            message_Root.updateChildren(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your FirebaseToken_Intent. If nothing exists in that variable or the variable is an empty string, Firebase won't store it.

Comment: If its null then it should add null into firebase table then adding nothing.But key should exist on firebase server with null value

Comment: @androidXP That's not how it works.  There is no such thing as a null value in Realtime Database.

Comment: @DougStevenson if value is null then firebase won't store any value?. If null then it also won't add key?

Comment: There can not be a key with no value.  If you try to set a key's value to null, the key will disappear.